# I keep getting invalid number of 'breaks' even though I followed what the R script said? (Posit Cloud)

Tags: statistics

```
>table(animal$animal.type)
>adultdogs <- adult[adult$animal.type == "dog",]
>hist(adultdogs$weight,main="Weight of Adult Dogs",xlab="Weight")
>adultcats <- adult[adult$animal.type == "REPLACECODE",]
>hist(adultcats$weight,main="Weight of Adult Cats",xlab="Weight")
```

I tried fixing the spacing and commas but neither work although all the previous lines run just fine beside histogram for cats.The histogram for dogs work.